# Java root and power of

Tags: java, math, double, exponent, square-root

I'm having trouble figuring this out:

Write a fragment that uses a for statement to set the double variable sum to the value of:
[image]

Here's what I tried:

```
class thing 
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    double sum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=25; i++)
    {
      sum += Math.pow(i,1.0/i) ;
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is wrong because it does not end with the proper calculation of 1.137411462.
Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: what do you mean by _" it does not end with the proper calculation of 1.137411462"_?

Comment: How could the sum of 25 numbers, all of which are `>=1` possibly be `1.13741162`?

Comment: @DnR actually I think I misunderstood the question woops, thanks though

Comment: One more question guys, why is it that I have to do (i,1.0/i) I sort of get it but not really. I was told to do this by someone else but I want to understand the code I'm writing @DavidWallace

Comment: if i= 25 then pow(i,1.0/i) =pow(25,1/25) that's what you want\

Comment: So is 1/25 like saying to the 25th root of 25 in that case @getlost

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 because `25√25` = `25^(1.0/25)` = `25^0.04`

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 yes DnR comment describe it better

Comment: @DnR that's 25 times the square root of 25. However, I need the 25th root of 25

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69, no, he meant the 25th root of 25.  It's just impossible to lay it out properly in the comment field.

Comment: Aha. `25th root of 25` is equal to `25 power of 1/25`, which is `25 power of 0.04`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the other replies above, that sum must start with 0, the calculation as you described isn't accurate.

The value of 25√25 is 1.137411462, not the sum from 1 to 25, in which case if you start with

```
int sum = 0;
```

You end up with the total: 30.85410561309813 which is the correct total that you want.

Answer (score 2):

change sum to zero at start .you are adding additiona 1 to sum.

```
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i<=25; i++)
{
  sum += Math.pow(i,1.0/i) ;

}

  System.out.println(sum);
```